# Applet: Unable to read image file

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have some problems calling ImageIO.read to read a file. This applet is embedded onto a HTML page, and I am using Javascript to return a string ("second"). Before calling ImageIO.read, the string "second" could be displayed. However after calling ImageIO.read, "second" could not be displayed. I want "second" to be returned back to the user after an Image file has been read.

Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <script language = "JavaScript">
    function bing()
    {
        alert(document.xyz2.Test());
    }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Value" onclick="bing()"/>
    <applet name="xyz2" code="xyz2.class" width=100 height=100>
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

**Applet Codes**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class xyz2 extends JApplet {
   public String s="first";
   public BufferedImage bf;
   public void init(){


   }
   public String Test() throws IOException{
       bf = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\rose.jpg"));
       s = "second";
       return s;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting an exception when reading the image from the file system. The applet needs to be **signed** to be able to touch those files.

Some choices:

- Sign your applet
- Read the image from the webpage you are accessing the applet from
- Embed the image in the applets resources

Comment: I tried to sign the applet but still nothing happens, I'm trying to get user to upload his own files from his machine, therefore embeding image will not be possible.